# read a int from a file wrote by java's writeInt method in C++?

Tags: java, c++, int, iostream

How would one go about doing this? Also, is there an easy way to do it? Using a lib like Boost or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154991/load-binary-file-using-fstream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataOutputStream which writes out the int writes out a 4 byte int, with the high bytes first. Read into char*, reinterpret and if you need to convert the byte order use ntohl.

```
ifstream is;
is.open ("test.txt", ios::binary );
char* pBuffer = new char[4];

is.read (pBuffer, 4);
is.close();

int* pInt = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pBuffer);
int myInt = ntohl(*pInt); // This is only required if you are on a little endian box
delete [] pBuffer;
```

Comment: All well and good until you hit a platform where `sizeof(int) != 4`. Or a one where integers are ones' complement or sign-bit, and not two's complement (all allowed by ISO C99).

Comment: On what platform are integers ones' complement or sign-bit? I would like to know.

Comment: @mamin: The PDP-1 used one's complement, and there are still three of them in existence (plus emulators).

Answer (score 2):

The only cross-platform way to do it is to read it byte by byte (that is, `char` by `char`), and build an integer out of them. You'd want to use `long`, because `int` is not guaranteed to be wide enough to hold a 32-bit value. I'll assume you've read the bytes into a `char[4]` array here (other answers have already demonstrated how to do that):

```
char bytes[4];
...
long n = (long(bytes[0]) << 24) | (long(bytes[1]) << 16) |
         (long(bytes[2]) << 8)  |  long(bytes[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1. Read it in as straight binary, then convert/interpret bytes as necessary.  So if Java wrote out 4 bytes for the int, then you read in 4 bytes.  If there is any endian-ness to change then do that, then cast (or copy) the byte array to a c++ int
2. If you can change the Java code, you could write it out as something common that C++ can read like UTF-8 text or ascii, or Google Protocol Buffers format or something else.