# Function template: read binary file into std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, stl

Problem: I'm trying to read a **binary** file into a `std::vector` with a template function: the reading into the vector doesn't work.

The file format I have to parse has some parts where all fields are guaranteed to have the same size: some parts of the file will contain an array of `uint16_t` fields, while some others will only be an array of `uint32_t`, or `uint64_t`, etc.

The base idea is to have a template function that reads into a `std::vector` passed as reference.

I tried to use [`std::vector.insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) or [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) but that doesn't work: the vector is always empty (I can guarantee that the file is accessible and can be read). I also checked the documentation about [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator).

That's probably just a trivial mistake, but I can't see what's wrong in the below code.

Problem repro code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, typename A>
void read_vec(std::ifstream& file, std::ifstream::pos_type offset, size_t count, std::vector<T, A>& vec)
{
    file.seekg(offset, std::ios::beg);
    //file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    /* Just test if we can read and dump the file
    T* p = new T[count];

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p), count * sizeof(T));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        T elem = p[i];
        std::cout << "e: " << std::hex << elem << std::endl;
    }
    delete(p);
    */


    /* //method #1
    file.seekg(offset, std::ios::beg);    
    vec.resize(count);

    vec.insert(vec.begin(),
        std::istream_iterator<T>(file),
        std::istream_iterator<T>());
    */

    // method #2
    file.seekg(offset, std::ios::beg);            
    vec.reserve(count);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<T>(file),
        std::istream_iterator<T>(),
        std::back_inserter(vec));

}

void parse_file_header(std::ifstream& f)
{
    std::vector<uint16_t> vec;

    read_vec(f, 0x40, 8, vec);

    for (const auto& elem : vec) {
        std::cout << "e: " << std::hex << elem << std::endl;
    }
}

void parse_file(std::string file_path)
{
    std::ifstream file(file_path, std::ios::binary);

    parse_file_header(file);
}


int main(void){

    parse_file("c:\\tmp\\t512_f.dexp");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A major problem is that the file is, apparently, a binary file, and when you use `std::istream_iterator` and `std::copy` like that it's like reading the numbers *as text*. I.e. it's the same as doing `int temp; file >> temp; vec.push_back(temp);` in a loop. You have to loop manually and use [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) instead.

Comment: Relative to [load-binary-file-using-fstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154991/load-binary-file-using-fstream).

Comment: Something wrong with your file (or file opening mode). Your code is working fine. See [live](http://rextester.com/ZSDU58393)

Comment: @user2451677 It works because your stream contains *text* and not binary data.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that's why I said "Something wrong with your file (or file opening mode)". Means that real situation is not the same as in the post

Comment: @user2451677 And what if the file exits, and the program have the rights to read, and more importantly it *is* a binary file? Then there is nothing wrong with the file and the open mode is correct. The problem is how the OP is trying to read from the file, the OP tries to read from it like it was a text file, but if it's binary file that method can't be used.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and all (can notify only 1 user in comments?): thanks a lot for your help!. Yes the file is a binary file, not a text file (I updated the question). I didn't know the problem was related to the file mode... It seems obvious now that I see your answers. For all commentators: If you wish to post your comments as answers, I could +1 all of you and accept the 1st to comment (@Joachim). Thank you!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `istreambuf_iterator` should work, no?

Comment: @T.C. I havent tested, but from my [reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) I think it should work.